# Using lightning component inside Aura:Iteration. It doesnt display anything not even any error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-iteration

Im using lightning component inside Aura:Iteration. It doesnt display anything not even any error.
PFB Code

```
<aura:component >
  <aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" required="true"/>
  <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
  <p>Name:
    <ui:outputText value="{!v.item.name}"/> 
   </p>

   <p>Quantity:
    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" style="currency"/> 
   </p>

   <p>Price:
    <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Price__c}" style="currency" /> 
   </p>

   <p>Camping :
    <lightning:input type="toggle" label="Packed" name="togglevalue" checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}" />
   <!-- <lightning:input type="toggle" packed="{!v.item.Packed__c}"/> -->
   </p>
   <p>
    <lightning:button label="Packed" onclick="{!c.packItem}" disabled="{!v.disabled}"/>                     
   </p>
</aura:component>
```

Camping:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="items" type="Camping_Item__c[]"/> 
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="obj">
      <c:campingListItem item="{!obj}"/>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

Comment: Could you share some more code to it? From what you're saying the reason may be that your 'items' attribute may not be populated. Please provide JavaScript code and check if you actually get any records from Apex.

Comment: You don't seem to have the complete code here. In its current form `items` attribute on your camping component is never populated, and thus if you iterate over it, you will get no results.

Comment: @JayantDas Do you mean, If i need to add query in controller to fetch the list?

Comment: Yes. You definitely need to first populate the list before you can iterate over it. In its current form, I don't see it being done, unless you are doing that already in your JS controller. If you are already querying the data and populating the list, then you can post that code here, so that specific problem can be identified.

Comment: I would recommend you can try to console.log(items) first to see if the item list is actually populated, I see nothing wrong with your component at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Without a full list of the code, it seems you are doing something like that:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.items}" var="item">
    <p>Quantity:
        <lightning:formattedNumber value="{!v.item.Quantity__c}" style="currency"/> 
    </p>
    <!--  -->
</aura:iteration>
```

If I am correct, change your code respectively to the following pattern: `"{!v.item.Quantity__c}"` to `"{!item.Quantity__c}"` . Here no value provider is needed

If my assumption isn't correct, please, provide us with `<aura:itereation>` as well

---

Ok, I see. There's nothing wrong with your code. Try to debug the data sent by the parent component and received by children ones, that's all I can suggest you